# Finding a method in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In Rails, I have a pretty normal `ActiveRecord::Base` class, I see the previous developer is using the `price` method in the `Item` model but I can't find where that method is, there is no column called `price` in the database but:

```
 [40] pry(main)> item.method(:price).source_location
   NameError: undefined method `price' for class `Item'
   from (pry):40:in `method'
  [41] pry(main)> item.price
   => 80.45
```

How so?

```
find ./ -type f -name "*.rb" | xargs grep "def price"
```

returns nothing. There is no alias or something like that. Where the heck is that method coming from?

Comment: can you do a search for just the string `price` and not `def price`? It may come from `method_missing` or even something buried in a gem.

Comment: Since ruby is dynamic method, it can be possible that s/he could have created a dynamic method or meta-programmed or defined it in some modules that is being included in the model.

Comment: has you tried this? `p item.method(:price)` ?

Comment: Answers belong in an answer, not in the question.

Answer (score 2):

If you're wondering where it comes from:

```
item.method(:price).source_location
```

Not every method originates from a `def`, in many cases they're generated using things like `define_method`, a module mixin, or other more exotic approaches.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys, yeah it was:

```
def method_missing(symbol, *args)
   if respond_to?(sym_to_cents_attribute(symbol))
```

since the column price_in_cents exists, it returns the price in dollars.